# Twitter: comparison of images on user_timeline and an image to be uploaded

Tags: python, image, twitter, tweepy

I'm trying to ensure that an image to be uploaded to Twitter is not the same as one that has previously appeared in the last 20 tweets.

The following function gets all image urls (from the last 20 tweets) on my timeline, then selects a random image from a directory to compare to that list of urls (clearly this won't work).

Is there a way to do a comparison of the image to be uploaded and the list of images on my timeline? For example, is there anyway to get the original filename of the image that has previously been uploaded, for a simple string comparison.

```
def testImageStatus():
    timeline_images = []

    for status in tweepy.Cursor(api.user_timeline, id=user, include_entities=True).items(20): 
        for url in status.entities['urls']:
            timeline_images.append(url['url'])

    while var == 1:
        selected_image = random.choice(os.listdir(DIR))
        if selected_image not in timeline_images:    
            picturecontent = "PICTURE : " + selected_image
            return selected_image
```

Comment: There is no info of the original filename on the tweet. You could download the images and do an image comparison but I guess it would be easier to keep a local list (text file or DB) of the last 20 images used and compare against that list.